# Regular expression to delete text

Tags: .net, regex

Okay, I have a variable where I am dumping employee names. The output looks like this

```
 1031;#Sharepoint Test Account 4,;#1898;#Smith, Bill
```

I just need employees name without the index number and pound sign. I tried this  `(?<=;#).*$` but not helping.

The output should be

```
SharePoint Test Account 4; Smith, Bill
```

Comment: regex outputs same as input.

Comment: Try this: ;?#?\d+;|# and call the replace method passing "" as replacement

Comment: @Gusdor: I have been trying different ways to but nothing is helping so now turning to stackoverflow. I am sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: With your regex `(?<=;#).*$`, You are matching everything to the end of the string with `.*$`. which will include the `;#1898;` part.

Comment: Define you question a little more clearly. In your expected output, for example, you have removed the comma after `4` but left the semicolon. If you input is just a bunch of records separated by `;#` can't you just split the string on that and take the second and forth records? Do you even really need regex here?

Comment: @UmarJamil: Your solution is almost perfect. The output is now #SharePoint Test Account 4, #Smith, Bill. just need to take care of the # sign at the beginning of each name. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Gusdor: The fact he provided some regex whether is good or bad shows he is trying to learn and attempted. Regex can be very complicated. It very discouraging to see negative flag or remarks.

Comment: @UmarJamil: Actually, your solution works. I had a extra space at end of the expression ;?#?\d+;|# it's working now. thanks. can you reply your answer so I can accept as answer.

Comment: @GreenCode: Actually that *does not* give you the output *you* said you wanted because it removes the semicolon between `4` and `Smith`. Your output would be `Sharepoint Test Account 4,Smith, Bill` which is *not* the same. Edit you question with what you *actually need* as an output.

Comment: @UmarJamil: The code is almost perfect. all I need is some characters between the names. the out put looks like SharePoint Test Account 2 Smith, Bill Miller, Denise.

Comment: This is the perfect choice for regex parsing. See my answer provided and don't let the naysayers distract you from learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this regex `;?#?\d+;|#` you'll have the desired output.

Comment: I kind of had to do this in two fold. First with this replace regex ;#+\d+;# and replace character being ; then I took the result output and add another replace regex \d+;# nothing to replace with then I got the result I wanted. Thanks for your help Umar.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you've given us, you don't need a regex at all. The simplest way would be to `Split` the string:

```
string input = "1031;#Sharepoint Test Account 4,;#1898;#Smith, Bill";
var cells = input.Split(new string[] {";#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// if you know the input strings will *always* conform to the same format
// you *might* be able to skip this check
if (cells.Length >= 4)    
{
    string output = cells[1] + ";" + cells[3];
}
else
{
    // the input was malformed and didn't conform to the expected format
}
```

`output` will be `Sharepoint Test Account 4,;Smith, Bill` I assumed the lack of the comma after `4` in your question was a mistake.

The above assumes that the input string always has the same format with at least three `;#` substrings (so you split to 4 cells) and the second and forth cells are the ones you are interested in.

Comment: Nitpick - Can you add a test for index count?

Comment: @Gusdor: Of course, you can, and probably should, in case an input does not have the expected number of cells after the split.

Answer (score 0):

Using this regex with named match captures one can extract the data and project the match results into anonymous entities for one to easily work with:

```
var text = "1031;#Sharepoint Test Account 4,;#1898;#Smith, Bill";

var pattern = @"(?<Value>\d+);#(?<Account>[^;]+)[;#]{0,2}";

var entities =
         Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
              .OfType<Match>()
              .Select (mt => new
                            {
                                Value =  mt.Groups["Value"].Value,
                                AccountName = mt.Groups["Account"].Value,
                            });
```

**Result**

[image]

---

**Update - A More Targeted Pattern**

```
var pattern = @"#(?!\d)([^;]+)";

Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Groups[1].Value)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this is really cool. But I really need one liner to take care of this. ;?#?\d+;|# works. All I need a ; going between the names.

Comment: @GreenCode See my update for a more one liner type pattern.